# Is there a way to extract multipart zip files without 3rd party tools?

Tags: c#, zip

I took a look at the ZipFile class but it does only support single files. So my question is: Is there any way to extract multipart zip files without relying on 3rd party tools?

Comment: You're kind of answering that yourself, aren't you? The only option without 3rd party libraries is to write your own. Otherwise, the answer is 'no'.

Comment: if you can execute shell command from C# you can use this command copy /b file1 + file2 + file3 test.zip and extract your file

Comment: By referencing `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`, my `ZipFile` has a static methods `ExtractToDirectory` and `CreateFromDirectory`. Does this help?

Comment: @spender good find wasn't aware they had added that in Net4.5

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer is not unless you write one yourself, the .Net compression system is geared towards streams not files, and as a stream can be a file, memory space, network traffic or a data feed from a device, enforcing file compression onto them would be a very bad thing

I tend to use [SharpZip](https://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/), its a free opensource library that handles some of the most common compression formats

Update:
looks like if you'rr using .net4.5 or higher ms has added the [ZipArchive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which allows you access directly to the windows zip manager (thanks to spender)